# Diodes circuit exercise

Tags: diodes, circuit-analysis

We have the following exercise in the figure:

[image]

I understand the answer. Now my question is: what is the output going to be if we would put V=10sinwt on the input? Could you sketch it for me?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend simulating this kind of problem to get an understanding. Then you can look at the voltages at different points in the circuit, see the current flows and easily insert different test voltages.

I knocked together a simulation in Paul Falstad's circuit simulator applet: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/. It's pretty quick and easy for simple circuits but doesn't have the power of a proper SPICE simulator.

[Here's the circuit in the simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#%24+1+5.0E-6+9.001713130052181+75+5.0+43%0Av+176+128+176+288+0+1+50.0+10.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Ar+208+96+256+96+0+10000.0%0Ad+288+160+288+128+1+0.805904783%0Ad+368+128+368+160+1+0.805904783%0Av+288+192+288+224+0+0+40.0+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Av+368+224+368+192+0+0+40.0+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Ar+368+256+368+304+0+10000.0%0Ar+288+256+288+304+0+10000.0%0Aw+176+128+176+96+0%0Aw+176+96+208+96+0%0Aw+256+96+288+96+0%0Aw+288+96+288+128+0%0Aw+288+96+368+96+0%0Aw+368+96+368+128+0%0Aw+368+96+432+96+0%0Aw+288+304+288+336+0%0Aw+288+336+368+336+0%0Aw+368+336+368+304+0%0Aw+368+336+432+336+0%0Aw+288+336+176+336+0%0Aw+176+336+176+288+0%0Aw+288+256+288+224+0%0Aw+288+160+288+192+0%0Aw+368+160+368+192+0%0Aw+368+224+368+256+0%0Ax+238+216+266+222+0+24+5V%0Ax+395+217+423+223+0+24+5V%0Ag+176+336+176+368+0%0Ap+480+240+480+192+0%0Aw+432+96+432+192+0%0Aw+432+192+480+192+0%0Aw+432+336+432+240+0%0Aw+432+240+480+240+0%0Ao+0+32+0+290+10.0+1.953125E-4+0+-1%0Ao+28+32+0+38+10.0+9.765625E-5+1+-1%0A).

The graphical output (with 1V per grid square on the scope) looks like this:
[image: simulated circuit]

The left hand graph at the bottom is the input function (in this case at 50Hz) and the right hand graph is the output function. You can see that the curve is the same when the input is between +-5V, but different (half the amplitude, but shifted up or down to make the function continuous) outside of these values.

Comment: P.S. If you want to draw the output of a simple piecewise function, the easiest way is to draw the input above each sub-function output separately then draw the boundaries down the page. You can then assemble the total output at the bottom by copying the correct sub-function for each section.

Comment: Yeah,this is what I need to understand,the output and the boundaries put in the same place.See another question of mine here to understand my explanation.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/127281/diodes-working-zone-graph-explanation

Comment: @user3543012 I added a description of the graphs at the bottom, so I am showing you the output here.

Comment: @Xcodo Would you describe the output as a bit of "soft" clipping?